# Php Search Script only pick up the first word

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

As the question, it only picked up the first word in my product_name which has var_char(50) as primary key.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = $_POST['searchquery'];
    if($_POST['filter1'] == "Whole Site"){
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (product_name ,details,category,subcategory) AGAINST ('".$searchquery."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    } 
    require_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count > 1){
        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $id=$row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                    $details= $row["details"];
                $category=$row["category"];
                $subcategory=$row["subcategory"];
            $search_output .= "ID: $id <br/> Name: $product_name -<br/>$details<br />$category<br/>$subcategory<br/>
<a href='product.php?id=$id'>link</a><br/>

";
        } // close while
    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Search the Exercise Tables</h2>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search For: 
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" maxlength="88"> 
Within: 
<select name="filter1">
<option value="Whole Site">Whole Site</option>

</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit">
<br />
</form>
<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

is this due to that it is a primary key? It actually not working for details as well, it actually very weird, not working for most words but work for some..i am totally confused..it is not making any senses

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
$search_output = "";

if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = $_POST['searchquery'];
    if($_POST['filter1'] == "Whole Site"){
$sqlCommand = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%s%%'",
               mysqli_real_escape_string($myConnection, $searchquery));
    } 

    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count > 1){
        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $id=$row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                    $details= $row["details"];
                $category=$row["category"];
                $subcategory=$row["subcategory"];
            $search_output .= "ID: $id <br/> Name: $product_name -<br/>$details<br />$category<br/>$subcategory<br/>
<a href='product.php?id=$id'>link</a><br/>

";
        } // close while
    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
    }
}





?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Search the Exercise Tables</h2>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search For: 
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" maxlength="88"> 
Within: 
<select name="filter1">
<option value="Whole Site">Whole Site</option>

</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit">
<br />
</form>
<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried above code as well and narrow down to product_name, it still not showing eg I have this product_name entered as 'omega fish' if i type 'fish' it doesn't show a single thing, if i type'omega' then it works

I have given this up and tried with the LIKE function and it seems to be better but still funny..please refer to this link for those that's interested

[PHP search script for mySQL database, only 3 letter working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187221/php-search-script-for-mysql-database-only-3-letter-working)

Thanks

Comment: Did you debugged that? Are you sure that the query itself provides wrong result (and there's no problem, for example, in user input)?

Comment: If $_POST['filter1'] != "Whole Site" then the $sqlCommand is null because you do not set the alternative $sqlCommand statement.

Comment: Did you check the html source code of the results page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this
[PHP search script for mySQL database, only 3 letter working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187221/php-search-script-for-mysql-database-only-3-letter-working)
i think this one is similar problem, just change the $count >1 to $count =0 or $count >=1