# PHP search script for mySQL database, only 3 letter working

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to do a php search into mySQL database. the following code works funny, it detect very well when I only entered 3 letter..eg i have a product name 'deepbluehealth omega' if i type 'ome' it picked up, if i type 'ega' it picked up, if i type 'omega' no result shown, also if i type 'deepbluehealth' it pick up no problem.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = $_POST['searchquery'];
    if($_POST['filter1'] == "Whole Site"){
    $sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, product_name FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR details LIKE '%$searchquery%') ";
    } 
    require_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count > 1){
        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $id=$row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                    $details= $row["details"];
                $category=$row["category"];
                $subcategory=$row["subcategory"];
            $search_output .= "ID: $id <br/> Name: $product_name -<br/>$details<br />$category<br/>$subcategory<br/>
<a href='product.php?id=$id'>link</a><br/>

";
        } // close while
    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Search the Exercise Tables</h2>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search For: 
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" maxlength="88"> 
Within: 
<select name="filter1">
<option value="Whole Site">Whole Site</option>

</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit">
<br />
</form>
<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
if($count > 1){
```

This needs to be:

```
if($count > 0){
```

To account for the case where there is exactly one result.  Probably this is the only product that matched "omega" but in every other case, another product happened to match.

Comment: sharp eye ive overlooked it.  if($count >= 1){  should also be possible and better to read.  It's better explaining that you need a count even big or larger then 1

Answer (score 1):

Nice random feature which I can not explain on the basis of the code only, could you give us the table structure / with indexes and some example data?

Extra tips

Don't use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] if you want to post to the same page because off the cross side scripting attacks that could happen now, or should use

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Yes you should leave the action empty

And

Run $search_output when you echo through the function htmlentities to countermeasue against to most cross side scripting attacks.

Comment: i removed the form action thingy, not sure what you meant by the $search_output thing, do you mean that the echo $search_output should be under html tag? instead body tag?

Comment: THis one <?php echo $search_output; ?>

Comment: yea but i did put the <?php echo $search_output; ?> under the body tag as shown above so all good right?

Comment: should be <?php echo htmlentities($search_output); ?>